# open a file in a function and use it in main

Tags: c++

I have a school project. The project requires me to write a function called openFiles. So I need to open a file inside the function and use it in main or other functions. How can I do that? Assumed my file is named "1"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
void openFiles(string);
main() {
    openFiles("1");
    string str;
    while(file>>str)cout<<str;
}
void openFiles(string str){
    fstream file;
    file.open(str);
    
}
```

Comment: Define `fstream` variable in `main`, and pass it as a reference to the function? I don't quite understand the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `fstream` has a [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor), you can return your `fstream` object as the result of `openFiles`, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

fstream openFiles(string);

int main() {
    auto file = openFiles("1");
    string str;
    while(file>>str)cout<<str;
}

fstream openFiles(string str){
    fstream file;
    file.open(str);
    return file;
}
```

Of course, you should check if the open succeeds.

Comment: Bah. Checking error condition is for the weak. Be a man and slam your head uselessly into a brick wall for hours to demonstrate your toughness and fitness to live.